# How to edit this Get Request VBA code so it does not skip line codes?

Tags: excel, vba, web, request, scrape

So this VBA code that webs scrapes a work website using the Get Request method skips all the lines after “For Each Div in Divs” and goes straight to end sub. Nothing is pasted on the sheet. This code I edited from using Internet Explorer and this code worked fine with that method but it was slow. Any ideas? Here is the code. Thanks in advance!

```
Dim Table As IHTMLElement
Dim Tables As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Div As IHTMLElement
Dim Divs As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim H3 As IHTMLElement
Dim TR As IHTMLElement
Dim TRs  As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TD As IHTMLElement
Dim TDs  As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Column As Integer

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup")
           
Row = 1
Column = 1
Set ws = Sheets("PROCESS")
ws.Cells.Clear

Dim H As Object, doc As New HTMLDocument
Set H = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")

URL = "WORK URL"

Debug.Print URL

ReTry:

H.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
H.setTimeouts 0, 0, 0, 0
H.Open "GET", URL, True
H.send
H.waitForResponse

If H.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox H.Status & " - " & H.statusText
    Exit Sub
End If

Debug.Print URL

doc.body.innerHTML = H.responseText

Set Divs =     doc.getElementById("secondaryProductivityList").getElementsByTagName("div")

For Each Div In Divs
    Set H3 = Div.getElementsByTagName("h3")(0)
   
    If Not Div.className = "floatHeader" And Not H3 Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(Row, 1).Value = H3.innerText
        Row = Row + 1
       
        Set Tables = Div.getElementsByTagName("table")
        Set Table = Tables(0)
        Set TRs = Table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each TR In TRs
            Column = 1
            Set TDs = TR.getElementsByTagName("th")
            For Each TD In TDs
                ws.Cells(Row, Column).Value = TD.innerText
                ws.Cells(Row, Column).Font.Bold = True
                If TD.getAttribute("colspan") Then
                    Column = Column + TD.getAttribute("colspan")
                Else
                    Column = Column + 1
                End If
            Next
                
            Set TDs = TR.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each TD In TDs
                ws.Cells(Row, Column).Value = TD.innerText
                Column = Column + 1
            Next
           
            Row = Row + 1
        Next
    End If
    Row = Row + 1
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I think "Set Divs =     doc.getElementById("secondaryProductivityList").getElementsByTagName("div")" giving you null/nothing result, thats why it skips. You need to check website or it has such elements, IF YES Then check "DIVS" object.

Comment: @bankeris but it worked perfectly when done with Internet Explorer. Why would that be?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you want to achieve here, but looking from logic side problem is in your Divs as it gives you nothing/null so for each has nothing to cycle through. Unless you give more details. So please before you reply DEBUG and see what DIVS give you or wait maybe someone else will help ya :)

Comment: Yes, the website has that element id. Just checked. Not sure why using the Get request method it skips this code line but using internet explorer method it does not @bankeris

Comment: It might have something to do with setting async to true for the GET request on this line `H.Open "GET", URL, True`. Try this instead: `H.Open "GET", URL, False`

Comment: Many pages have dynamic content which is added by script after the page has loaded.  That doesn't happen when using a single GET request outside of a browser: you just get the page source and that's it.

Comment: @TimWilliams I get that but this code when slightly tweaked worked using Internet explorer method